# How to run react-native on visionOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, virtual-reality, visionos

Apple just released visionOS SDK for creating Vision Pro apps. How can I run a react-native project on Apple Vision Pro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your app on visionOS is just a matter of adding it as a supported destination.

Select your app target in your project’s settings and navigate to the General tab. In Supported Destinations, click the Add (+) button to add a new destination and select the Apple Vision option.

[image: Xcode project]

After that just select Apple Vision Pro (Designed for iPad) from you run destinations list and press run

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Previously you had to use XCode's compatibility mode to run React Native apps on visionOS however this was a very limited approach.

In early 2024 the folks at @callstack announced support for React Native apps targeted to visionOS that can take full use of the platform. You can create a sample project by running the following command:

```
npx @callstack/react-native-visionos@latest init MySpatialApp
```

You need XCode, command line tools, and Vision Pro simulator installed on your Mac development machine for it to properly work. If you're looking for a quick walkthrough there's increasing write-ups on this, such as the following:

[Create a React Native App for VisionOS](https://ergin-d.com/blog/react-native-visionos-app)

For additional info you can also checkout the [visionOS developer page](https://developer.apple.com/visionos)